# Angular 5 testing cannot use fakeAsync

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I working on unit tests and I'm trying to test a component method that contain a `Promise`, after the promise is executed I redirect the user. I want to test the route path so I use `fakeAsync` and `tick` to wait for the promise to finish but I get this error :

> TypeError: Right-hand side of 'instanceof' is not an object

I really don't know what is wrong, I've done the same thing than the doc.

Here is the component :

```
@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    styles: [ require('./_login.component.scss') ],
    template: require('./_login.component.html'),
})

export class LoginComponent {
    public loginForm = {
        password: '',
        username: '',
    }

    constructor (
        private loginService: LoginService,
        private router: Router
    ) 

    public submitLoginForm () {
        this.loginService.log(this.loginForm.username, this.loginForm.password)
            .then((value) => {
                this.router.navigateByUrl('/home')
            })
    }
}
```

And here is the test

```
describe('Component: LoginComponent', () => {
    let component: LoginComponent
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>
    let loginMockService: LoginService
    let location: Location

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                LoginComponent,
                MockComponent,
            ],
            imports: [ NxtModule, RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([{ component: MockComponent, path: 'home' }]) ],
            providers: [
                { provide: 'AppStore', useValue: appStore },
                { provide: LoginService, useValue: loginService },
            ],
        })

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent)
        component = fixture.componentInstance
        fixture.detectChanges()

        loginMockService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(LoginService)
        location = TestBed.get(Location)
    })

    it('should log', fakeAsync(() => {
        spyOn(loginMockService, 'log').and.callThrough()

        component.loginForm.username = 'john.doe@test.com'
        component.loginForm.password = 'password'
        component.nxtForm.updateForm('username', component.loginForm.username, true)
        component.nxtForm.updateForm('password', component.loginForm.password, true)

        component.submitLoginForm()

        expect(loginMockService.log).toHaveBeenCalled()

        tick()

        expect(location.path()).toEqual('/home')
    }))
})
```

If I remove the `fakeAsync` and the `tick` it works but I can't test the `expect(location.path()).toEqual('/home')`, I've tried everything : remove node_modules and pacakge-lock.json and run `npm i`, updating Angular to v5.0.5, etc.

Thank you

Comment: exactly where/when are you getting this error? I mean is there any specific line number. error has something to do with assignment. somewhere assignment is not correct.

Comment: you can also debug on your own in browser's console window.

Comment: now I have something different, here is the error : `TypeError: undefined is not a valid argument for 'instanceof' (evaluating 'proxyZoneSpec.getDelegate() instanceof FakeAsyncTestZoneSpec') in sources/tests.entry.js (line 140794)`